# How to combine $V$($3\times 3$ matrix) from $V^{-1}XV$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

$V_i$ and $X$ are $3\times 3$ matrices.
$$V_k-V_{k-1}=V_k^{-1}XV_k$$
How to get $V_k$ if $V_{k-1},X$ are known?

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEOwi.png)

it is continous system, i discrited that but how to get the $$R_b^l$$ only?
this is the book links
[It is on page 180](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642304651)

Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please share the context in which you encountered the problem (e.g., homework or theorem in a book) and some of your own thoughts of how to approach the problem, and we will be happy to guide you further.

Comment: @gt6989b :)., okay i edited the question..

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you told us what book this comes from. Is it available on the internet or a well-known work? The picture you included only gives formulas but not much more context than the question as it was. Adding the source could help you get an answer :)

Comment: @Student : okay, i edit it again.. :)

Comment: I think it need some transformation matrix like quaternion..

Comment: Sorry, i just read the whole page about it and found that it is solved by quaternion transformation.. thank you for your help.. :)